# ERROR: gcloud crashed (ServerNotFoundError): Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to sign in to the cloud sdk with the command: `gcloud auth login`, and I select my google account in the browser. After I click allow, in the terminal it says:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ServerNotFoundError): Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

And when I run the command gcloud info --run-diagnostics it also stops with the error:

```
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (ServerNotFoundError)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.
```

My config is the default one without any modifications. 
I could sign in with no issues to the cloud sdk for a long time.
I am on windows 10.
I tried signing in both with the cloud sdk shell and the windows terminal, as administrators and not as administrators.

How do I fix this error?

UPDATE:
I run the `tracert -4 www.googleapis.com` and also `-6` command and this is the result:

```
Unable to resolve target system name www.googleapis.com.
```

I am working from home, and I don't know what a network proxy is, I might be accidentally using one.

Comment: You are experiencing a network problem at your location. Perform a trace route from your desktop to  www.googleapis.com. On Windows run this command: `tracert -4 www.googleapis.com`. Repleat replacing `-4` with `-6`. This might help you figure out where the network failure is occurring. Linux has similar commands. Update your questions with the results and more details about your network, such as are you working from home, your office, the country, use of a network proxy, etc.

Comment: I updated you with the results

Comment: You have a DNS problem on your computer. What DNS servers are you using? What country are you in? The command `ipconfig /all` will show your network configuration.

Comment: I went to work and now I am back, it is working. Maybe the server shut down for maintenance or something

Comment: It was likely a DNS error.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147067/httplib2-servernotfounderror-unable-to-find-the-server-at-www-googleapis-com/71589505#71589505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have enabled proxy with gcloud, use-> gcloud config list to get the proxy settings

To unset proxy use: gcloud config unset proxy/[params]  where params are address, port etc.

Comment: Once can also check the value of `https_proxy` variable. Sometimes it is used to set proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login into your gcloud SDK first using this command

```
gcloud auth login
```

It will open a google sign up page in the browser. Select your account and then you will get a conformation in you command line that you have been authenticated. Then try what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when connected to VPN. **Disconnected from VPN** and ran the below command and it worked.
*gcloud auth login*

Comment: Now I'm getting this error instead: `An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets?fields=spreadsheetId&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'method': 'google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.CreateSpreadsheet'}}]">`